# (hive) Insert failed: row_number () over partition by with problem

Tags: hadoop, hive, sql-insert, row-number

I am using the ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY...) and trying insert to insert, but dosen't works:

> ERROR:  FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing
>   invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input
>   columns. Also check for circular dependencies. Underlying error:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 120:59 .
>   Operator is only supported on struct or list of struct types
>   'dur_rel_chamada' (state=42000,code=40000)

Ex.:

````
ORDER BY numero_a, numero_b, data_atendimento, hr_chamada, ABS(1*horario_originacao - 1*horario_originacao_fcdr), dur_rel_chamada, dur_tar_chamada,
tp_cdr_fcdr, duracao_atend_fcdr DESC, duracao_total_fcdr DESC)as ordem_originacao_bilhete_dist ```
````

Comment: try to reduce your code to the shorter one which reproduces the error

Comment: Leticia, could you please localize the problem and provide FULL smaller query, not part of it. Sorry I mislead you with my first comment. You provided too long and complex query first. I believe you could provide some minimal example which reproduces the same behavior. This error can be if you have analytic and not-analytic functions on the same level, or if row_number is enclosed in some other aggregation function and usually it is possible to fix using sub-queries